# Github Actions: How do I loop through each input type for manual workflows

Tags: github, gradle, yaml, github-actions

As of right now the only thing I know how to do is access the input the user puts in through the variable github.event.inputs.name

Here is a working example of my yaml file

```
on:
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      name:
        description: 'Pick a cat'
        type: choice
        options:
          - Cat1
          - Cat2
          - Cat3
jobs:
  greet:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, windows, cat]
    steps:
      - name: Print Greeting
        run: echo "Hello, ${{ github.event.inputs.name }}!"
```

Ideally I would like to loop through the default options Cat1,Cat2,Cat3 in the yaml and print each value out. The end goal is for me to pass these values into build.gradle. Passing into build.gradle is not difficult but I couldn't find documentation on how to specifically list out each options under inputs:

Here are some of the documentations that I read:

https://github.blog/changelog/2021-11-10-github-actions-input-types-for-manual-workflows/

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_dispatchinputs

This is one of the examples they had where they tried accessing it from the variable:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      logLevel:
        description: 'Log level'
        required: true
        default: 'warning'
        type: choice
        options:
          - info
          - warning
          - debug
      print_tags:
        description: 'True to print to STDOUT'
        required: true
        type: boolean
      tags:
        description: 'Test scenario tags'
        required: true
        type: string
      environment:
        description: 'Environment to run tests against'
        type: environment
        required: true

jobs:
  print-tag:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if:  ${{ inputs.print_tags }} 
    steps:
      - name: Print the input tag to STDOUT
        run: echo  The tags are ${{ inputs.tags }}
```

I tried doing different variations of this solution but it always came out empty. I know this example was with tags but I tried doing the same way with  loglevel but it didn't work

Comment: Can you clarify on the requirements further? I'm a bit confused.